# Mosquitto MQTT how we know when topics created

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am using mosquitto MQTT protocol. I want to know when queue created in MQTT broker ,while publishing or subscription or both subscription and publishing?

**$SYS/broker/clients/connected** displays number of connected clients, at the same can we find number of queues in MQTT broker..?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you don't.

MQTT uses *topics* not *queues* (this is important as they are very different concepts) and a topic basically only really exists at the moment a message is published to it.

When a message is published the broker checks all the existing subscriptions for any that matches and then delivers that message to those clients with the matching subscription.

A queue is a mechanism where normally messages are collected and each message is only delivers to one client no matter how many are connected to the queue. With a topic messages are delivered to every client that has a matching subscription.